# How to change the number of cells within each main grid area in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

As seen in the following screenshot each main grid container in a [draw.io](http://draw.io) diagram has x 4x4 matrix of cells.

[image]

I would like to change it to 5x5. How can that be achieved?  I looked at the *Diagram* menu and it has a configuration for "Points" but not for number of cells:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click Extras > Configuration in the diagrams.net editor and you will
see the default
{
"gridSteps": 4
}

Change the number to 5, click Apply and then reload a page.

P.S If you don't see "gridSteps": 4, just add

{
"gridSteps": 5
}

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: There is _nothing_ in that dialog.  I have added the _{ "gridSteps": 5 }_ manually.